# Why sending message crashes when clicking button for third time?

Tags: swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I set up sending message to phone numbers in my project and works fine. I click the `button`,iPhone sending message page pops up, if I send a message or click `Cancel`, it goes back. Now if I click the button for second time, nothing happens, if I click for third time, app crashes. The info in console told me to change Use afterScreenUpdates:NO to `Use afterScreenUpdates:YES` . So I added `controller.view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)` in my code, but it didn't work. What needs to change here?

in console:

```
Cannot snapshot view (<UIKeyboardImpl: 0x101a224f0; frame = (0 0; 320 216); layer = <CALayer: 0x170622880>>) with afterScreenUpdates:NO, because the view is not in a window. Use afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

My code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController,  MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

var phoneNumber = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {   
    super.viewDidLoad()

     messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
 }    

@IBAction func sendMessageTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let recipient = self.phoneNumber  // I get self.phonenumber from other code, no problem.

        messageVC.body = ""
        messageVC.recipients = [recipient]

    self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
  // I added this line to fix, didn't work.   
//  controller.view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)


    switch result.rawValue {

    case 0 :

        print("Sending Message cancelled")

        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    case 1:

        print("Message sent")
        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    case 2:

        print("Sending message failed")
        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    default:
        break
    }
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the `MFMessageComposeViewController` personally, but looking at the error I can make a guess that it might not like being presented more than once. Have you tried only creating the `MFMessageComposeViewController` instance when you are about to show it instead of keeping a reference to it in memory and reusing it?

Comment: Seems more a comment than an answer. But a *good* comment. :)

Comment: @dlbuckley Good guess! I created MFMessageComposeViewController instance when clicking the button. Now it works fine! Thanks.

Comment: No worries! Just remember when you find bugs like this to file them with Apple (http://bugreport.apple.com/). It's a pretty rare case but if you found it then someone else might find it too, so it's bet to let Apple know so they can fix it in the future.

Comment: @dlbuckley yes, it is pretty rare. I use imagepicker and similar stuff, never encountered this. Will file with apple. good point.

Answer (score 1):

I get same issue. It's work for me.

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
}
```